# Numbering your code filenames when possible : Do's and Don't?

Tags: python

TL,DR: Is it a sacrilege to number your code source files in their executing orders ?

I'm developing a very small program in Python, which execution is very sequential.
Kinda looks like a script.

I thought about numbered the source files and librairies by their order of execution, when possible. To me it brings the same clarity in the folder organization, exactly as you would number the chapters of a book...

For transversal functions that can be called at any step of the program they are in files named by their functionalities.

Is it an absolute don't do? Why ?

here is an example of how my project folder looks:

```
Project_0_main.py
Project_1_step_yyy.py
Project_2_step_xxxx.py
Project_3_step_zzzzz.py
Project_math_functions.py
Project_do_that_function.py
```

Thanks

Comment: I would not do this.  As soon as you need to change any of the logic you will also need to do significant refactoring to update the module names to match.

Comment: Is the numbering really going to help you find which bit of code lies in which file?

Comment: Past 10 files in the folder, I find that it improves navigation and readability to have them in order.
And if I need to change the logic, I rename the files via the refactor functions of IDEs, they change all the references made to the files inside the code, so it's only a few clicks.

Comment: Name your modules based on *what those modules are for*. That's the point of modules - not simply to split code across multiple files so that each file is smaller, but to split functionality into logical units which can be maintained separately. A module should do what it is supposed to do regardless of which other module is importing it.

Comment: If you've never looked at source code for other projects, then maybe you don't know that this practice is rarely if ever done.  If you've been around pretty much forever, like I have, then knowing that nobody does this should tell you something.  If this was a good idea, you wouldn't be the first to think of it or try it.  Nobody does this.  It's not a good idea....IMHO anyway.

Comment: Also if all of your filenames begin with `Project_` then it seems like you are trying to use filename prefixes as a poor substitute for [directories](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directory_(computing)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only question that matters is about maintainance. If you are sure that you could possibly adapt steps but never add a new step between 2 other ones, then numbering is fine, even if is is not the most common use(*). It you cannot be sure of that, then you have just find the *don't* and the reason why.

---

It is not a absolute *don't*, but naming scripts with sensible names related to the real actions is a form of minimal, implicit and immediate documentation. Using numbers will lose that, and would require an annex file to document what is done in each numbered step.